# Making digital clock- why my given minutes and seconds start from 0?

Tags: c, scanf

After inputting a specific time, my minutes and seconds start from 0. Can anyone point out the mistakes in my coding please?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    int h=0,m=0,s=0,i;
    system("cls");
    printf("Please enter a time format in HH:MM:SS\n ");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&h,&m,&s);
    start:
    for(h;h<24;h++)
    {
        for(m;m<60;m++)
        {
            for(s;s<60;s++)
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t%d:%d:%d",h,m,s);
                if(h<12){printf("AM");}
                else {printf("PM"); }
                for(double i=0;i<99999999;i++)
                {i++;
                i--;}
            }
            s=0;
        }
        m=0;
    }
    h=0;
    goto start;
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

If I input `22:23:32`, it will show to start from `22:0:0`.

Comment: You don't check `scanf` result. The format `%d%d%d` can't read 22:23:32.

Comment: Try `scanf("%d:%d:%d",...)`

Comment: `scanf()` doco says the function returns the number of variables assigned... Check return values of all functions. They are trying to tell you things you want to know.

Comment: PS: "Self Help Section" Try assigning 17 instead of 0 to h, m, and s at the top of the function... You'd see some interesting results...

Comment: PS: Ordinarily, using a 12hr clock requires AM/PM... Displaying a 24hr clock probably shouldn't display "18:57:00 PM"... Redundant...

Comment: The loop `for(double i=0;i<99999999;i++)` is not accomplishing anything except spinning -- which the compiler is free to optimize out. Generally you just see this type loop on microcontrollers as a delay. If that is your case, you may want to look at what your board and compiler actually provide in the way of timers or sleep capability.

Answer (score 3):

The colon separators in your input are causing the `scanf` call to fail (after reading the `h` value), as they cannot be interpreted as integers (as expected by the `%d` format specifiers).

If you *know* that your time input will *always* have the two `:` characters separating the hours, minutes and seconds values, then you can include those in the format string you pass to `scanf` – which will then look for (and skip) **exactly** those characters between the integer inputs.

Also, you should get into the habit of always checking the return value of `scanf`, to see if it successfully read the required number of fields:

```c
    //...
    int check = scanf("%d:%d:%d", &h, &m, &s);
    if (check != 3) { // Failed to read three integers
        printf("Invalid input!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to fix your format string to match your input, and check the return value from `scanf()` to ensure you actually read the data you expected.  You probably want to print `h % 12` as you use AM/PM.  I suggest you use sleep instead of the busy loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {
    printf("Please enter a time format in HH:MM:SS\n ");
    int h, m, s;
    if(scanf("%d:%d:%d",&h,&m,&s) != 3) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for(;;) {
        for(;h<24;h++) {
            for(;m<60;m++) {
                for(;s<60;s++) {
                    printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t%02d:%02d:%02d %s",
                        h % 12,m,s,h < 12 ? "AM" : "PM");
                    sleep(1);
                }
                s=0;
            }
            m=0;
        }
        h=0;
    }
}
```

and example run:

```
Please enter a time format in HH:MM:SS
 13:2:3



                        01:02:03 PM


                        01:02:04 PM
```

The next step would be to setup a timer at regular intervals as `sleep()` will skew when it's run sufficiently long.  Use `strptime()` and `strftie()` if they are available to you.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to @AllanWind for the correct user input code, there's the following that doesn't have quite the same level of indent and has been adapted to a Windows environment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main () {
    printf( "Enter a time (format HH:MM:SS)\n ");
    int h, m, s;
    if( scanf( "%d:%d:%d", &h, &m, &s ) != 3 ) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    for( int ds = ((h*60)+m)*60+s; ;ds = (ds+1)%(24*60*60) ) {
        printf( "%02d:%02d:%02d\n", ds/(60*60), (ds/60)%60, ds%60 );
        Sleep( 1000 ); // NB: Uppercase func name and time in mS...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
23:59:57
23:59:58
23:59:59
00:00:00
00:00:01
00:00:02
```

The program should give the processor *some* exercise through calculating the quotients and modulo remainders from 86400 seconds per day... With a tiny tweak to the hours value, the counter could be left to simply count up, up for the next 136 years (as an unsigned 4byte integer.)